# Open new window with mvvmcross

Tags: xamarin, uwp, mvvmcross

The root window of Xamarin application is a menu. I am using MVVMCross and would like for each menu option to open a new window. I have been trying to use the instructions from the below link to show another view....

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/show-multiple-views

However, I'm not sure how to wire-up MVVMCross on the new view for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

With MVVMCross for Xamarin you can use **ShowViewModel< YourViewModel >();**

For example :

```
private MvxCommand _changePageCommand;

public IMvxCommand ChangePageCommand
{
    get
    {
        _changePageCommand = _changePageCommand ?? new MvxCommand(DoChangePageCommand);
        return _changePageCommand;
    }
}

private void DoChangePageCommand()
{
    ShowViewModel<YourViewModel>();
}
```

Bind this command on your button.

Comment: Correct, but what logic is needed to actually have this view model open a NEW window. I assume it will require some tinkering with presenters?